# Pointwise convergence of Fourier series of function $\sqrt{|x|}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. Show that the Fourier series $s_n(0)$ converges to $f(0)$.

The hint is that one should consider the convolution with the Dirichlet Kernel and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. This approach yields $$s_n(0) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\frac{\sin[(N+1/2)t]}{\sin t/2}dt = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\sin nt\cot(t/2)dt + \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos nt dt,$$ and while the integral on the right tends to zero, by R-L, I could not estimate the integral on the left. This seems to come primarily from the fact that $\cot t/2$ behaves quite poorly around $t = 0$, with $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\cot x = \infty$.

I have searched a few elementary texts on PDE's, including Folland's, Evans' and Strauss', and I could not find any examples of pointwise convergence questions with a function of unbounded derivative. Moreover, the only related question that I found on MSE was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586041/convergence-of-fourier-series-at-x-0) one, but in this case the function is odd and the integrals vanish trivially. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is not a periodic function.  So what do you really mean by "the Fourier series"?

Comment: You can just define it on an interval around $x = 0$ and extend it periodically. It makes no difference on the convergence at $x = 0$

Comment: Note that
$$
\sin(nt) = \sin t \left[ (2 \cos t)^{n-1} - {n-2 \choose 1} (2 \cos t)^{n-1} + {n-3 \choose 2} (2 \cos t)^{n-3} - \dots \right],
$$
and since $\sin t \cot(t/2) = 2 \cos^2(t/2)$, we have 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \sin nt \cot \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) = 0.
$$This may be enough for you to estimate the integral.

Comment: As long as $f$ is monotone or more generally of bounded variation, then the Fourier series converges to the average of left and right-hand limits at a point.  The answer just follows the steps of the proof of this theorem (Jordan convergence test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is even so this reduces to an integral over $[0,\pi]$.  Consider the contributions from $[0,\delta]$ and $[\delta, \pi]$ separately.

The contribution over $[\delta,\pi]$ converges to $0$ directly by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma since $f(t)/\sin(t/2)$ is integrable on that interval.

For the contribution over $[0,\delta]$ use the fact that $f$ is nondecreasing and continuous. By the second mean value theorem, there exists $\xi \in (0, \delta)$ such that

$$\int_0^\delta f(t) D_N(t) \, dt = f(\delta)\int_\xi^\delta D_N(t) \, dt$$

By continuity, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a sufficiently small $\delta$ such that for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \delta$, we have $f(x) < \epsilon$.

Again using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we have as $N \to \infty$,

$$\left|f(\delta)\int_\xi^\delta D_N(t) \, dt \right| \leqslant \epsilon\left|\int_\xi^\delta D_N(t) \, dt \right| \to 0 $$

Therefore, $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(0) = 0 = f(0).$